# Understanding a medieval approximation

Tags: approximation, math-history, irrational-numbers

A medieval text ([Maimonides](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides)'s commentary to chapter 2 of *Eruvin* in my retranslation from the Hebrew) discusses a rectangle whose area is $5000$ square cubits. It reads in relevant part:

> … that the length should not exceed the width except to such an extent that the diagonal is double the width. Then the length of the region will be $93\frac1{27}$…. All these reckonings are approximate….

"The diagonal is double the width" amounts to $\sqrt{L^2+W^2}=2W$ of course. The length $L$ is then $\sqrt{5000\sqrt3}\approx93.0605$, between $93\frac1{17}$ and $93\frac1{16}$.

**Where might he have gotten $1/27$ from?**

Note that I'm *not* asking "How could he be so far off?". I'm asking specifically about the number $93\frac1{27}$ and why he may have that as a solution as opposed to, say, $93\frac1{24}$ or $93\frac1{30}$.

Comment: It could be that he was implicitly using successive divisions into thirds, and this was the appropriate approximation. Put another way, working in base $3$, $10110.001_3 = 93 + \tfrac{1}{27}$ is $\sqrt{5000\sqrt{3}}$ rounded down to the nearest $0.001_3$.

Comment: @Travis maybe (and nice find)… but then why?

Comment: I'm not sure, answering that at best probably requires knowing something specific about the mathematical practices of his historical context.

Comment: Or he could have made an arithmetical error. What numerical system was he using?

Comment: AS I recall the gemara there uses a pretty good approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ but still off somewhat.  Perhaps Rambam was using that value and therefore arrived at the figure you mention. I would suggest using the gemara's approximation of root 2 to see what you get.

Comment: What is the original Hebrew text?  Is it found in Chabad's online text with English translation  http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935286/jewish/Eruvin.htm ? The "Chapter Two" link does not seem concerned with geometric measurements, and I couldn't easily find online another chapter that does deal with diagonals of rectangles etc.

Comment: @MikhailKatz if it were just $\sqrt{5000}$ then knowing $\sqrt 2$ would suffice, but here there's also a factor of $3^{1/4}$.

Comment: @Noam https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Eruvin.2.5?lang=bi

Comment: Thanks, or should I write "תודה".  Travis May be right, because the fraction 1/27 is written as "a third of a ninth"!  Curiously the width is given as only 53⅓ (and plain 53 in the diagram; the correct value is nearly 53.7285), and the diagonal which is supposed to be twice that as 107½ (this is closer to 107.457).  There's quite the long digression just before about the side of a square of the same area (is that the $\sqrt2$ approximation that @MikhailKatz referred to earlier?): is it nearly 70 and 5/7 or 70 and 2/3?  (The former is much closer to the actual $70.711678\ldots$.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, that it's written "a third of a ninth" *may* be a quirk of the translator. (Maimonides wrote his commentary in Arabic, not Hebrew.) I don't know enough Arabic to be able to read the original and tell whether "a third of a ninth" appears there.

Comment: Are you sure of this?  The *very* little Arabic I know could be just enough to tell whether he wrote $1/3\times 1/9$ or $1/27$, but according to the Wikipedia entry for *Mishneh Torah* it's written "in Hebrew in the style of the Mishnah", even though "His previous works had been written in Arabic."

Comment: @Noam this is not _Mishne Tora_ but his commentary to the _Mishna_.